# displaying a smaller UIWebView as a form sheet

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, modalviewcontroller

I'm trying to pop up a UIWebView on iPad with a web site that is specifically sized for the iPhone (320x480).  I want the web view to be centered, and transition in using a zooming animation.  Other apps have this functionality, but I can't seem to find out how to do it.  I've tried various combinations of presentation & transition style, but no matter what I do, the web view takes up the entire screen and slides vertically to cover the screen.  I've made the web view 320x480 in IB, and am using UIModalPresentationStyleFormSheet, which should make it at least slide up into the center of the screen using a small window, but that is not occurring.

anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you setting the property of the parent `UIViewController` or the modal `UIViewController`? Because you should be setting the properties of the modal `UIViewController` before presenting the controller instead of the parent.

This might be no help at all because you're doing the right thing, but it was the first error I made when starting to use MVCs.

Comment: turns out this was the problem - i thought the modal presentation properties were to be set on the parent and not the presented modal view.

Answer (score 0):

maybe any of the autosize property is set. just do one thing bind your webview with the code and through code try to set the frame. Hope it will work as it worked many times to me when i faced similar types of problem.

hAPPY cODING...

Comment: this wouldn't solve the transition.  while i care that the view covers the whole screen, i care more about the transition being used.  other apps seem to be able to pop open a web view that bounce zooms into view.  i've not been able to do this yet.